# meteor 0.5.7: how to handle/use Meteor.Collection.ObjectID?

Tags: meteor, objectid

I have updated my meteor yesterday and tried using the new `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID`.
But since with no success. First i updated my collections in this way:

`myCollection = new Meteor.Collection('mycollection', {idGeneration: 'MONGO'}`
Now, normal new inserts have an `_id` like `Wi2RmR6CSapkmmdfn`... (?)

Then i have a collection with an array included. I like to have an unique id for every object in this array. So i `$push` an object with a field like `id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()` into my array. The result in the database is like this: `ObjectId("5b5fc278305d406cc6c33756")`. (This seems to be normal.)

But later i want to update my pushed object, if the `id` equals an id, which i stored as data attribute in an html tag before.

`var equals = EJSON.equals(dbId, htmlId);` (This results every time in `false`. So i logged the values `dbId` and `htmlId` into the console with `console.log(typeof dbId, dbId);`)

The values of this two variables is as follows:

`object { _str: 'a86ce44f9a46b99bca1be7a9' }` (dbId)

`string ObjectID("a86ce44f9a46b99bca1be7a9")` (htmlId; this seems to be correct, but why is a custom type a string?)

**How to use the `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID` correct?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When placing your `htmlId` in your html you need to put it in as a string and not as an object, remember `_id` is an object now, handlebars is guessing and using `toString()` & thats why it shows up as `ObjectID("...")`.

So if you're using `{{_id}}` in your html you now need to use `{{_id.toHexString}}` to properly extract the string part of it out

When you extract this html value with your javascript you need to make it back into an objectid:

js:

```
var valuefromhtml = "a86ce44f9a46b99bca1be7a9"; //Get with Jquery,DOM,etc

htmlId = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(valuefromhtml); //see: http://docs.meteor.com/#collection_object_id

EJSON.equals(htmlId, dbId); //Should be true this time
```

Comment: **Thank you for the quick answer! :)** Btw: `{{_id.toHexString}}` is not working directly, but i registered a global handlebars helper, which does this job.

Comment: It should work without a helper, I tested it before posting do you have other pre Meteor 0.57 object ids?

Comment: Hmm... I have deleted my collections, but my handlebars debug helper, which prints a given value in the console, prints nothing, when i call him with `{{debug _id.toHexString}}`. I have looked at the minimongo sources and `{{_id._str}}` works directly (`ObjectID.toHexString()` returns `_str`)