# Meteor update Mongo Doc by ID

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to update a Mongo record via Chrome's console.

`Posts.update('hexidhere', {$set: {title: 'something text here'}});`

The problem is with docs that were created a Mongo terminal. They were assigned an id like so (_str and _proto are nested inside the _id):

```
_id: LocalCollection._ObjectID
_str: '54ff06801ad15adbb3d1090'
_proto: LocalCollection._ObjectId   
title: 'dummy title here'
```

When I added another test doc via chrome's console (not a mongo terminal) It seems to have added an ID correctly, and everything works as expected:

```
_id: 'EtPt9ntXtxG4qo9Tb'  
title: 'dummy title here'
```

**My question is:**
Does anyone know a way to make the ID always be simple HexStrings (like in the second example), or is there a correct method for accessing the nested str value in the LocalCollection (I've tried Mongo.ObjectID('hexidhere'), 'theidhere', and a whole bunch of other stuff)?

Comment: Not sure it fits your need, but have you read this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041128/meteor-0-5-7-how-to-handle-use-meteor-collection-objectid ?

Answer (score 1):

Mongo likes to use `ObjectId` for `_id`, Meteor opted to use `String`. To learn more see the now deprecated google groups convo: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/f-ljBdZOwPk

To get the string of an `ObjectId` use the `str` method as in `ObjectId("310458asdf323452").str` See here for more info: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

Comment: Thank you for this! I had to delete all the documents with `ObjectId` objects for `_id`s, and insert new documents (via Meteor `<collection>.insert`, not Mongo shell) to replace them. Then it started working for me.